# What causes SunCC crash in g3mangler.cc when using `-std=XXX`?

Tags: solaris, sunstudio, solaris-studio, suncc

I'm trying to determine what is causing SunCC 5.11 - 5.13 to die with `../lnk/g3mangler.cc, line 825` (message from SunCC 5.13). Here's what it looks like during a compile. The machine is a 4th gen Core i5, so its got the features which correspond to the macros.

```
/opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/CC -DDEBUG -g3 -O0 -std=c++03 -D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__
-D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__ -D__AES__ -D__PCLMUL__ -D__RDRND__ -D__AVX__ -xarch=avx
-m64 -native -KPIC -template=no%extdef -w -erroff=wvarhidemem -erroff=voidretw -c gcm.cpp
 >> Assertion:   (../lnk/g3mangler.cc, line 825)
    while processing gcm.cpp at line 408.
```

I know the problem surfaces with `-std=c++03` on all the compilers, and `-std=c++11` on the newer compilers. If I omit `-std=XXX`, then the problem goes away. Telling users they cannot use C++03 or C++11 is not viable.

Here is `gcm.cpp:408`. Its basically commented out now due to efforts to isolate. In fact, deleting all the code and leaving an empty function witnesses it, too:

```
MAYBE_INLINE void GCM_Base::ReverseHashBufferIfNeeded()
{
#if BOOL_AESNI_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE
    // if (HasCLMUL())
    {
        // __m128i &x = *(__m128i *)(void *)HashBuffer();
        // x = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x, s_clmulConstants[1]);
    }
#elif BOOL_ARM_CRYPTO_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE
    if (HasPMULL())
    {
        if (GetNativeByteOrder() != BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER)
        {
            const uint8x16_t x = vrev64q_u8(vld1q_u8(HashBuffer()));
            vst1q_u8(HashBuffer(), (uint8x16_t)vcombine_u64(vget_high_u64((uint64x2_t)x), vget_low_u64((uint64x2_t)x)));
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

`MAYBE_INLINE` is a macro I am using to toggle `inline` on and off for the compiler.

The only reports I can find on the web are from our bug tracker. I'm out of ideas since I've exhausted all the code in the function.

What causes the SunCC compiler crash in `g3mangler.cc` when using `-std=XXX`? How can we work around it?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience on the old Sun forums, a failed assertion in one of the Solaris Studio components is *always* considered a compiler bug.

You'll likely be better served posting your issue to [the Oracle forum for Solaris Studio](https://community.oracle.com/community/server_&_storage_systems/application_development_in_c__c++__and_fortran/developer_studio_c_c++_fortran_compilers).

You can also try different [`-compat=`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37075/bkamw.html#OSSCPbkanr) and [`-std=`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37075/bkamw.html#OSSCPgnaof) options.  In particular, `-std=sun03` may work for you (but it will not produce GNU C++-compatible binaries).